# Does Selenium only work Javascript sites? (BeautifulSoup works but Selenium does not)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from google finance with following link
https://www.google.com/finance/quote/ACN:NYSE

The section I am trying to fetch is on right side containing information like market cap, p/e ratio etc.
[image]

Earlier I thought it was javascript and wrote the following snippet:

```
class_name = 'gyFHrc'
options = Options()
options.headless = True
service = Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
browser = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
browser.get(base_url+suffix)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15)
wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name))) # <--line 58
stuff = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)
print(f'stuff-->{stuff}')
for elem in stuff:
    html = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    # print(f'html:{html}')
```

I get the following error:

```
File "scraping_google_finance_js.py", line 58, in <module>
    wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)))
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/scraping/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16
```

Later, I realised that this was plain HTML and I can use BeautifulSoup as follows:

```
class_name = 'gyFHrc'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
box_rows = soup.find_all("div", class_name)
print(box_rows)
for row in box_rows:
    print(type(row), str(row.contents[1].contents))
```

This worked with following output:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> ['$295.14']  
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> ['$289.67 - $298.00']  
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> ['$261.77 - $417.37']  
.....
```

The question is, why did it not work with Selenium? Did I do something wrong? or Selenium only works with Javascript site?

Clearly time to load the page was not the problem as BeautifulSoup could fetch and parse the page

Answer (score 1):

The error *selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException* says the element you are trying to load or find is not found within the given time.

Probably your internet is slow to load the stuff in time. Increase the wait time to get the result.
This error usually happens when selenium can't find the desired tag or element. But in your case, the element was there.

I checked the code with a few changes, and it worked for me so it's probably an issue with the element loading in time.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


class_name = "gyFHrc"
driver.get("https://www.google.com/finance/quote/ACN:NYSE")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)))  # <--line 58
stuff = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)
print(f"stuff-->{stuff}")
for elem in stuff:
    html = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    print(f"html:{html}")
```

Result

[image: Results]

Comment: thank for the elegant solution. `ChromeDriverManager().install()` is very neat and versatile. It works with your solution I am now trying to remove this chrome window asking to accept / reject cookies. Maybe there are options to auto reject it.


May be it does work with Firefox cause I do not have Firefox installed on my machine?